# Read content from drupal wysiwyg editor using jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

So I am using wysiwyg tinymce editor for my drupal site. I want to read/get all the data which is written in the editor using `javascript/jquery`. How can I achieve it?
Was expecting `$('#tinymce p).text()` would help but it does not.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the JQuery Plugin with TinyMCE ([http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:jQuery_Plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x%3ajQuery_Plugin)) you can get the content like so:

```
$('#someeditor').html()
```

If you are NOT using this plugin, use the getContent method ([http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)) like so:

```
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()
```

Comment: Thanks oliakaoil,                                                    it works i got the active editor id using                                var id=Drupal.wysiwyg.activeId; and then  tinyMCE.get(id).getContent();